# Parameter within module name

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I'm writing a module assertion `bind`:

```
module top_assertion #(parameter WIDTH=8) (input rtl_signal);

axi_``WIDTH``_bus axi_bus;

assert property (@(posedge Clock) !$isunknown(axi_bus.valid);

endmodule

bind rtl_module top_assertion#(8) assertion(.*);
```

Idea being using different axi_buses (Ex: axi_8_bus, axi_32_bus, axi_64_bus interfaces) depending on what `WIDTH` `parameter` is passed. I *could* write with axi_8_bus, axi_32_bus, axi_64_bus instances explicitly hardcoded but I want it to be dynamic instead.

It seems ``` axi_``WIDTH``_bus ``` isn't valid though.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The ``` `` ``` syntax is used with `define` compiler macros, not parameters.

You could use a `generate` construct with a `case` statement to conditionally declare the interface you need based on the `parameter` value:

```
module top_assertion #(parameter WIDTH=8) ();

case (WIDTH)
    8 : axi_8_bus  axi_bus ();
    32: axi_32_bus axi_bus ();
    64: axi_64_bus axi_bus ();
endcase

//..(assertion checks on axi_bus)..

endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27.5 *Conditional generate constructs*.  The `generate` keyword is optional.

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you know, but again, there's no way to stick a variable into module name? That would have been neat crisp code. How about I use define compiler macro within assertion code file :D? `define axi_bus(width) \  ```axi_``WIDTH``_bus  axi_bus;``` module top_assertion #(parameter WIDTH=8) (); axi_bus(WIDTH); endmodule

Comment: you can write a generator script to generate code with different module names. There also are tricks which you can play with defines and inludes, but it is not recommended and considered bad practice. There is no clean way in verilog to do what you want besides *generate* blocks as shown in the answer.